# How to use a Telerik client side event to trigger a backend C# method?

Tags: c#, telerik

Noob to programming here, please help :)

I am using a Telerik RadComboBox to make a dropdown list with checkboxes. When the dropdownlist closes, on OnClientDropDownClosed event, I want to send a List or array of the selected items to C# in a ascx.cs file.

However, OnClientDropDownClosed is a client side event and I have been stuck trying to make this work.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlRegions" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
    DataTextField="Name"     DataValueField="Id"
    AllowCustomText="False" MarkFirstMatch="False" 
    OnItemsRequested="ddlRegions_ItemsRequested"
    OnClientDropDownClosed="OnDdlRegionsClosed" 
    OnClientItemChecked="OnClientItemChecked1"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="False" Filter="Contains" Width="100%" 
    EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"     RenderMode="Lightweight" 
    CheckBoxes="true" Skin="Bootstrap">
</telerik:RadComboBox>

//Get all checked items from dropdownlist and add to a List or array
public void OnDdlRegionsClose
{
    regions = string.Empty;

    foreach (RadComboBoxItem chkRegion in ddlRegions.CheckedItems)
        {
            regions += chkRegion.Text + ",";
        }
        //removing last comma
        regions = regions.ToString().Substring(0, regions.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: You could make an ajax call?

Comment: I never used Ajax. Do you have some example ?

Comment: A very simple example **[Here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the [RadAjaxManager](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/client-side-programming/overview) and send requests to server-side with it.

For example: [ajaxRequest(arguments)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/client-side-programming/overview#ajaxrequestarguments) or [ajaxRequestWithTarget(eventTarget, eventArgument)](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajaxmanager/client-side-programming/overview#ajaxrequestwithtargeteventtarget-eventargument)